# Java recursive method end but doesn't terminate

Tags: java, eclipse, list, recursion, linked-list

I was writing a method for a doubley linked list data structure that is supposed to reverse a list of elements from index a to b, as specified in the parameters, and decided to do it recursively. The objective of the assignment was to practice pointer manipulation using nodes. The logic for my method seemed okay to me, but when I ran the code through a JUnit test it wouldn't end. Thinking this was strange, I added println statements to see which parts of the code it reached; everything checked out okay. So I ran it through Eclipse's debugger, and it reached the ending bracket, after going forward and back through all of the recursive calls, without terminating. It just sat at the end bracket, and I've never seen anything like this before. Why is it doing that and what can I do to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
public void reverseList(int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }

    ListNode left = getListNode(start);
    ListNode right = getListNode(end);
    ListNode leftNext = left.next;
    ListNode leftPrev = left.previous;
    ListNode rightNext = right.next;
    ListNode rightPrev = right.previous;

    leftPrev.next = right;
    rightPrev.next = left;
    leftNext.previous = right;
    rightNext.previous = left;
    left.next = rightNext;
    left.previous = rightPrev;
    right.next = leftNext;
    right.previous = leftPrev;

    reverseList(start + 1, end - 1);
}
```

EDIT: Here is code to test it

JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testReveseList()
{
StudentList list = new StudentList();
list.add("a", "");
list.add("b", "");
list.add("c", "");
list.add("d", "");
list.add("e", "");
list.add("f", "");
list.add("g", "");
list.add("h", "");
list.add("i", "");
list.add("j", "");
list.printlist();
list.reverseList(2, 5);
System.out.println();
StudentList expectedList = new StudentList();
expectedList.add("a", "");
expectedList.add("b", "");
expectedList.add("f", "");
expectedList.add("e", "");
expectedList.add("d", "");
expectedList.add("c", "");
expectedList.add("g", "");
expectedList.add("h", "");
expectedList.add("i", "");
expectedList.add("j", "");
assertEquals(expectedList, list);
list.reverseList(2, 5);

System.out.println();

StudentList expectedList1 = new StudentList();
expectedList1.add("a", "");
expectedList1.add("b", "");
expectedList1.add("c", "");
expectedList1.add("d", "");
expectedList1.add("e", "");
expectedList1.add("f", "");
expectedList1.add("g", "");
expectedList1.add("h", "");
expectedList1.add("i", "");
expectedList1.add("j", "");
assertEquals(expectedList1, list);
list.reverseList(0, 9);
System.out.println();
StudentList expectedList2 = new StudentList();
expectedList2.add("j", "");
expectedList2.add("i", "");
expectedList2.add("h", "");
expectedList2.add("g", "");
expectedList2.add("f", "");
expectedList2.add("e", "");
expectedList2.add("d", "");
expectedList2.add("c", "");
expectedList2.add("b", "");
expectedList2.add("a", "");
assertEquals(expectedList2, list);

}
```

Test Class:

```
public class StudentList
{
private ListNode head = null;

public void add(StudentData data)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(data);
    ListNode lastNode = getTail();

    if (lastNode == null)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        lastNode.next = newNode;
    }

    newNode.previous = lastNode;
    newNode.next = null;

}       

    public ListNode getListNode(int indexOfDesiredNode)
{
    if (indexOfDesiredNode >= size())
    {
        // --- Error: There aren't that many nodes
        return null;
    }

    // --- Move through the list, node by node, until we find
    // --- the one we want
    int count = 0;
    ListNode current = head;
    while ((count < indexOfDesiredNode) && (null != current))
    {
        current = current.next;
        count = count + 1;
    }

    // --- So, did we find anything?
    if (null == current)
    {
        // --- Error: We didn't find the node
        return null;
    }

    return current;
}

    public int size()
{
    if (null == head)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return count;
}

    public void reverseList(int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }

    ListNode left = getListNode(start);
    ListNode right = getListNode(end);
    ListNode leftNext = left.next;
    ListNode leftPrev = left.previous;
    ListNode rightNext = right.next;
    ListNode rightPrev = right.previous;

    leftPrev.next = right;
    rightPrev.next = left;
    leftNext.previous = right;
    rightNext.previous = left;
    left.next = rightNext;
    left.previous = rightPrev;
    right.next = leftNext;
    right.previous = leftPrev;

    //-- The easy way of doing it... *sigh*
    // StudentData temp = get(start);
    // getListNode(start).data = getListNode(end).data;
    // getListNode(end).data = temp;

    reverseList(start + 1, end - 1);
}
}
```

And ListNode class:

```
public class ListNode
{
public StudentData data = null;
public ListNode next = null;
public ListNode previous = null;

public ListNode(StudentData data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return data.toString();
}
}
```

I'm sorry that the formatting isn't the greatest, that happened with copy & paste.

Comment: It should work. The problem could be in the `getListNode` call. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please?

Comment: It's a tail-recursive function; so after the last recursive call actually returns, you just keep implicitly returning from each successive call by reaching the end of the function. Are you sure it never terminates?

Comment: getListNode was written by my instructor so I'm positive it works. It just returns the node at a specified index.

Comment: @user2900718 So can you post a working example? Assuming that the `getListNode` method works correctly, your code just works.

Comment: In eclipse, it will not show the println statements infinitely printing, but I have to manually terminate the program.

Comment: @BackSlash what do you mean by a working example? I too thought that my  code should just work, that's why I'm confused and came here.

Comment: @user2900718 I mean, post an example class which uses that method. We will try it and tell you what is wrong

Comment: We need a "Self Contained" problem description. That means a minimal but full example of code showing this problem so we can run it.

Comment: I posted the code @BackSlash

Comment: @TheBrogrammer Your code is incorrect, it doesn't compile, so your example is not working. I tried to fix some parts of your classes (like the `printlist` method which was missing and the wrong `add` invocation) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @BackSlash it definitely compiles, I only copied the parts of code which were necessary for the reverseList() method which may have caused some errors. But after you fixed those errors my method worked for you?

Comment: @TheBrogrammer Yes it compiles and runs fine. I notice you are using JUnit: I had some problems with JUnit, such as the application freezing without a real reason. Probably it's me that don't know how to configure it. However, try running your application _without_ a JUnit test and it should work as expected

Comment: @BackSlash I ran it in an Application class using the main method to add letters to a list and reverse them, but the method still doesn't terminate. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @TheBrogrammer I use NetBeans. From your classes it seems you are using a JUnit test for the method. If you are not using a JUnit test then there must be something wrong in your full code, check it, your recursive method just works. In fact if the recursion was infinite, it would have thrown a `StackOverflowError`: it doesn't, so this means that the recursive method is not the problem here

Comment: @BackSlash thank you! I hope to figure out why the problem lies within my IDE. If you would like to submit an answer so I this thread can be "solved" that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the case when `end == start + 1`, hence `rightPrev == left`. You then set `rightPrev.next = left` which makes your list circular, so `getListNode` won't terminate.